# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, node.js, installation

I've been working with `node.js` `v0.6.3`, locally installed on *Windows Vista* at `C:\Program Files\Nodejs`. I recently upgraded to (by running the installer for) `v0.6.6`. It seemed like it worked for a while, but now if I try to run `node` from any directory I get a

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

message, though running `node` from `C:\Program Files\Nodejs` *does* work.

I tried rebooting, removing node, reinstalling, reinstalling 0.6.3 - nothing seems to work. I just don't get *why `node` fails to recognize system path, though `node` works from its base dir?*

Comment: looks like you haven't added your node folder to your PATH variable. Also, you need to define a NODE_PATH variable. In *nix anyway, not sure about windows

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Node is missing from the SYSTEM PATH, try this in your command line

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

and then try running `node`

To set this system wide you need to set in the system settings - cf - http://banagale.com/changing-your-system-path-in-windows-vista.htm

To be very clean, create a new system variable `NODEJS`

```
NODEJS="C:\Program Files\Nodejs"
```

Then edit the `PATH` in system variables and add `%NODEJS%`

```
PATH=%NODEJS%;...
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Solved the problem, though I could have sworn I had checked (and manually changed, etc) the PATH variable beforehand, too. Perhaps it has a matter to do with "/" [not] appearing at end of PATH variable, and/or nodejs path needs to be BEFORE rest of path (rather than end)?

Anyway, works for now and I've learned how to set path from CMD to boot, so thanks :)

Comment: I had the same problem, but removing the trailing '/' from the PATH fixed things for me for some reason.

Comment: Thanks!! Adding "C:\Program Files\Nodejs" to the PATH var in windows settings didn't work for me. Setting it like this in command line did!

Answer (score 46):

Nodejs's installation adds nodejs to the path in the environment properties incorrectly.

By default it adds the following to the path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

The ending `\` is unnecessary. Remove the `\` and everything will be beautiful again.

Comment: amazing, after over a year they still have not fixed this

Comment: amazing, after over three years, they still have not fixed this.

Comment: 2018 here and still going strong not fixing it :)

Comment: 2020 now, assuming it still aint fixed :)

Answer (score 18):

Go to the folder in which you have Node and NPM (such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`) and type the following:

```
> set path=%PATH%;%CD%
> setx path "%PATH%"
```

From http://www.hacksparrow.com/install-node-js-and-npm-on-windows.html

Comment: And remember in win7 you can shift-right-click a folder, or empty space inside a folder, and 'open command window here'

Answer (score 6):

Everytime I install node.js it needs a reboot and then the path is recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Watch out for other paths ending in \ too. I had this:

```
...bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

and changed it to this:

```
bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

removing the final \, but it still didn't work. The previous path, for the Web Platform Installer, had a trailing \ too. Removing that fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion helped me to solve the problem! I had trailing "\" in another path variable

Comment: Worryingly, there were loads of trailing "\"'s in the PATH variable. Including SQL Server entries and System32 entries. But this fixed my problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `C:\Program Files\Nodejs` to your `PATH` environment variable. The `PATH` environment variable allows run executables or access files within the folders specified (separated by semicolons).

On the command prompt, the command would be `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Nodejs`.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this on your terminal (CMD) and it should work just fine:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure nodejs in the PATH is in front of anything that uses node.

Answer (score 0):

I set the NODEJS variable in the system control panel but the only thing that worked to set the path was to do it from command line as administrator.

SET PATH=%NODEJS%;%PATH%

Another trick is that once you set the path you must close the console and open a new one for the new path to be taken into account.

However for the regular user to be able to use node I had to run set path again not as admin and restart the computer

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the above steps, but the issue didn't resolve. So I uninstalled and installed node.js and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the above steps, but the issue didn't resolve. So I uninstalled and installed node.js and it worked for me.

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin