# Nodejs on Win7 - use npm only through Nodejs command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a question about usage of Nodejs.

I installed it on Win7 and run (green Node.js icon) it, but when I tried to run "npm install" command it dodn't work. I had to move to  Nodejs command prompt where npm is working.

Is that how it supposed to work?

Comment: No, I can call npm update from anywhere. Do you mean you had to move to the folder where node is installed? What error do you get?

Comment: If you had the command window open at the time of install, the path wouldn't have been adjusted. So, you'd need to start a new command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you install NodeJS under Windows, it goes into the global PATH, meaning that it is available in the usual Windows command prompt. So, just open one by pressing:

1. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then type `node -v`. You should be able to see an appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

Add your AppData\Roaming\npm and Program Files\nodejs folder to your path.

Also have a look at this:
[Node.js doesn't recognize system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-js-doesnt-recognize-system-path)

Second answer helped me to add my Roaming folder.