# Setting NodeJS path in Windows XP for SublimeLinter Framework

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I am using Windows XP and using Sublime Text 3 build 3126.  I'd like to use the SublimeLinter framework with it, but they are listing NodeJS as a dependency.  How can I ensure that NodeJS is available on my system path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js doesn't recognize system path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-js-doesnt-recognize-system-path)

Comment: No, I haven't set the path yet. So the system, of course, didn't recognize it.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+set+the+path+on+windows+xp

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=what+is+the+latest+version+of+windows+xp

Comment: so its time to change bro

Comment: I did it using the environment variable after trying to post it about a bunch times in to the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prevent node from running and installing on Windows Vista or earlier.**

**[Windows XP and Vista are no longer supported](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5167)**

*Launching the msi, with Windows Installer 5.0 (it's available as an update)*

[image]

*Launching the msi, with Windows Installer < 5.0*
[image]

**What about Node.js v0.10 and v0.12?**

If you're still currently using Node.js v0.10 or v0.12, it is time to begin the transition to v4 or v6. Both v0.10 and v0.12 are considered to be in Maintenance mode currently and will **fall off our support plan completely later this year**.

**What about Node.js v5?**

Node.js v5 will continue to be **supported for the next two months** in order to give developers currently using v5 time to transition to Node.js v6.

if you still want to proceed with xp setting the environment see this link

[Setting up HTTP server on Windows with Node.js](http://www.jhh.me/blog/2012/12/24/setting-up-http-server-on-windows-with-node-js/)

**[Windows XP support has ended](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14223/windows-xp-end-of-support)**

find about latest version here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/936929