# Node.js error, nodemon server crashes and starts rebuilding

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I have cloned a Node.js project from GitHub and stored it on my Mac. I also cloned the repo on my Windows. Now, after I run the commands `npm install` and then `npm run dev`, I get issues on my Windows only, but not on Mac. On Mac, the server runs fine and the website is hosted on localhost. On Windows, the error says

> node is not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Then the `nodemon` error says

> app crashed.

I looked up for suggestions, and it was recommended to set the Node.js path in environment variables. But it didn't help.

Could you please advise me on the possible solutions?

Comment: Try running it in git bash or WSL, not the regular Windows cmd.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)