# How do I fix npm err in vscode gitbash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQFUE.png
I configured gulp and later during the process when installing the next plugin there was such an error. What is it connected with and how to solve it? (VSCode,GitBash)

Comment: I'd recommend you install node - not sure how to do that in mingw

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score -1):

I'm a new user as well trying to answer questions. Since I need a certain amount of reputation to comment, I have to go with an answer.

Double check if node is installed and run `node -v` If it is, than the issue might be (unlikely) related to your code so we might need a sneak peak of it to answer this question