# How to run 'npx create-react-app' command successfully in VS Code terminal on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a MERN-based tinder app but faced error in the very first command. When I ran 'npx create-react-app tinder' in VS code terminal, I got this error message -

```
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npx create-react-app tinder
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

I have Node.js installed on my system. Below are two things I have tried, but they didn't work.

1. I tried running `node -v` in VS Code terminal to check if VS Code is able to recognize Node.js. But on running this command, I got the following error message:

   ```
   node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
   At line:1 char:1
   + node -v
   + ~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   ```

   Note that on running version commands for Node and NPM on Windows PowerShell and command prompt, I am able to see their versions as output (v16.18.0 and 8.19.2 respectively) confirming their presence in my system.
2. Nonetheless, I tried running `npm install -g create-react-app` command in VS Code terminal next and the following is what I got:

   ```
   npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   At line:1 char:1
   + npm install -g create-react-app
   + ~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
   ```

I suspect that this problem may be due to some path setting that I need to do correctly. My folder named 'tinder' and Node.js are in different drives (Tinder is in E drive and Node.js is installed in C drive). Is that the reason for error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['node' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)